# How do I create a new calendar event based on a range of times?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, calendar

Our app displays opening times, e.g "Mon: 09:00 - 11:30", in a UITableCell. When the user taps the cell, I would like it to pop up a screen which lets the user create a new calendar event for the given opening time (so e.g. repeating every monday between 09:00 and 11:30).  Is there a built in controller I can use, like there is for adding a contact?  If so, how do I use it?  If not, what should I use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple provides a framework called EventKit for handling the calendar. You can use a class called EKEventViewController, which is not so customizable, or make your own view and interact directly with the calendar using simple EventKit methods.

There's a very good explanation + sample code at [apple developer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKitUI/Reference/EKEventViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009572)

Comment: EKEventViewController is just what I want - customisation is evil!